# Replicated table distribution for small dimension in SQL Data Warehouse (Azure Synapse) with 1 Compute Node

Tags: azure-synapse

Microsoft provides [design guidance for replicated table distributions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/design-guidance-for-replicated-tables) in SQL DW, but it's not clear to me if there are advantages to this distribution type for small service tiers (sub DW1000) where only one compute node is allocated.

Do low-end service tier deployments with a single compute node benefit from this distribution type for small dimensions (e.g. country, calendar, etc.), or should a different distribution option be selected?

Comment: Seems like this is the same as ROUND_ROBIN until you swap to a tier with an additional compute node.

Comment: If you join a round-robin table to a distributed table you will see shuffle steps in the query plan. It still does distribution compatible joins even though it’s all on one node because it’s still separated into 60 distributions. However if you join a replicated table to a distributed table you will likely not see a shuffle. So replicated tables do make sense even on small DWU service tiers.

Answer (score 0):

There is an advantage to replicate tables on all tiers. Remember that the Azure Synapse SQL has nodes and distributions spreading data across the storage. So Synapse SQL will replicate the data across the distributions.  The whole idea of replicate tables and distributed tables is to reduce data movement. Take a look at the replicated tables diagram in [this](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2014/07/30/transitioning-from-smp-to-mpp-the-why-and-the-how/) blog.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes you will benefit from replicated tables even on small DWUs.
The reason for this is because when you execute your query, this query is divided into 60 queries that are running. So newer forget that you always have 60 distributions regardless of the number of DWUs. Replicating means that you would always have a full copy of your replicated table on every distribution. So, this is the reason because with replicated tables you would eliminate shuffling which is great for your query execution. (In other words, the query would have all data on distribution on which is running.)

Also, you have to keep in mind that Microsoft is saying that good candidates for replicated tables are tables that are <= 2 GB. You can guess that with replication you will bring additional storage costs because your table will occupy 60 x current storage due to replication. But as always, optimization is a trade-off between some values.

Comment: It is a bit confusing, because it seems that replicated table is distributed not on every 60 distributions, but on every node, so in case of 1 node, it is almost standard ROUND_ROBIN table and I see it on my replicated table using command DBCC PDW_SHOWSPACEUSED('table')